# How solve this RuntimeError in django

Tags: python, django

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCVca.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIiro.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSLjv.jpg)

I'm learning Django with Web Development with Django.

In chapter 4 of the book... The author wants to Customize admin

I do according to the book... But Django give that RuntimeError  .

What's the solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.